# /dev/mem can't acccess as normal user

Tags: memory, raspberry-pi

So I have an electronics project which involves colored LEDs called Neopixels. The supplier of the LEDs has written a library in order for my Raspberry Pi to change its color. But it uses `/dev/mem`. For reasons am not too sure.

Anyway, I was wondering if I can have read and write access to memory without running as root. It makes debugging the Python script harder because the editor doesn't run as root hence it can't access `/dev/mem`. This means I can't debug my python script.

I tried `chmod 775 /dev/mem` then added my username to the group it belongs to. However I still get can't open `/dev/mem` permission denied error.

Comment: For me to permit ordinary user to access entire memory is against the philosophy of Linux. Access it as `root`

Comment: You've been provided low-quality "code" that is a kludge and should be avoided. Using that method could conflict with the proper operation of pinctrl and gpio, and could result in an unstable system. The proper way to "*change color*" would be either syscalls to kernel drivers, or use an API for userspace. Inspect **/proc/iomem** to determine which device(s) you are hacking with those memory accesses.